# Create a new worksheet and insert an event into it automatically

Tags: vba, excel, events

I have a question, if something what I want to do is possible.

I have a workbook and a macro which creates new worksheets in that workbook.
But I need these worksheets with an event inside (deactivate worksheet).

Example: My macro creates worksheets called "Resources_1", "Resources_2", "Resources_3" (and it can create more worksheets later). Every of this worksheet has an event Worksheet_Deactivate and one line of code inside.

Maybe any of you have an idea how to do that? If it is possible to do?

EDIT:

As rory suggested, I've tried to make a workbook level event but it doesn't work. On deactivate any of worksheet (except 4 of them), I want to hide its.

My code in 'ThisWorkbook' module:

```
Public wsEvent As Worksheet

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    If wsEvent.Name <> "General" And wsEvent.Name <> "Projects" <> wsEvent.Name <> "Resources" And wsEvent.Name <> "ResourcesProjects" Then
        Set wsEvent = ActiveSheet
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    If wsEvent.Name <> "General" And wsEvent.Name <> "Projects" <> wsEvent.Name <> "Resources" And wsEvent.Name <> "ResourcesProjects" Then
        wsEvent.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It is possible, but I would suggest that instead you use a template sheet which already has the code in it and copy that, or use a workbook level event instead which will be triggered for all sheets in the book (if you need to excluded a few, your code can check the names, or a property of the sheets.

Comment: @Rory's suggestion of a workbook-level event that checks whether the worksheet that triggered it begins with "Resources," sounds like the correct approach. It will be much easier to maintain.

Comment: Nice idea, thank you for that, but I have some troubles. I edited my question and add my code there, maybe someone could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need in your `ThisWorkbook` module is this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Select Case LCase$(Sh.Name)
        Case "general", "projects", "resources", "resourcesprojects"
            ' skip
        Case Else
            Sh.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh, it works! Thank you again :) I'm weak with events, I must learn more about that :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Rory and Doug's comments. Although I am inclined for Rory's actually that is the one I usually use, less code to maintain.

There is this article from http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx that explains how yo achieve what you need, search for keyword "Creating An Event Procedure"

I hope this helps :)